# Progress Dialog when opening Json fed Listview

Tags: android, json, listview, progressdialog

I have an app that loads information from a json feed into a listview.  This takes a moment to load, so I would like to set up a progress bar to let users know the app is doing something.  Do I have to implement an AsyncTask, or is there a simple way to get the spinning progress icon to appear while the list is loading?  I'm assuming I need to place the progressdialog code in the task that I am loading.  Here is my code for my listview.

```
public class Schedule extends ListActivity {

protected EditText searchText;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected TextView textView;
protected ImageView imageView;
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule);

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.gradiant);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {
                    0xFF95B9C7, 0xFF06357A });
    gd.setCornerRadius(2f);

    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

    myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL("myAPIURL");

    try {

        JSONArray current = json.getJSONArray("d");

        for (int i = 0; i < current.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = current.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("showid", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("ShowID")));
            map.put("name", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Title")));
            map.put("showvenue", "" + e.getString("ShowVenue"));
            map.put("subtitle", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("SubTitle")));
            map.put("venueid", "" + e.getString("VenueID"));

            String showDate = e.getString("ShowDate");
            long epoch = Long.parseLong(showDate);
            Date showDatePresent = new Date(epoch * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMMM d");
            String dateOfShow = sdf.format(showDatePresent);
            map.put("showdate", "" + dateOfShow);

            String showStart = e.getString("ShowStart");
            long epoch2 = Long.parseLong(showStart);
            Date showTimePresent = new Date(epoch2 * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            String timeOfShow = sdf2.format(showTimePresent);
            map.put("showstart", "" + timeOfShow);

            String showEnd = e.getString("ShowEnd");
            long epoch3 = Long.parseLong(showEnd);
            Date showEndPresent = new Date(epoch3 * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            String endOfShow = sdf3.format(showEndPresent);
            map.put("showend", "" + endOfShow);

            String gatesOpen = e.getString("GatesOpen");
            long epoch4 = Long.parseLong(gatesOpen);
            Date gatesOpenPresent = new Date(epoch4 * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "'Gates open: 'h:mm a");
            String gatesAreOpen = sdf4.format(gatesOpenPresent);
            map.put("gatesopen", "" + gatesAreOpen);

            map.put("aboutartist", "" + e.getString("AboutArtist"));
            map.put("program", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Program")));
            map.put("programnotes",
                    "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("ProgramNotes")));
            map.put("pricing", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Pricing")));
            map.put("featuring", "" + e.getString("Featuring"));
            map.put("parkdetails", "" + e.getString("ParkDetails"));
            map.put("starred", "" + e.getString("Starred"));

            map.put("image500", "" + e.getString("Image500"));

            map.put("image250", "" + e.getString("Image250"));

            map.put("aboutartist",
                    "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("AboutArtist")));
            myList.add(map);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList,
            R.layout.line_item, new String[] { "name", "showdate",
                    "showstart", "showvenue" }, new int[] { R.id.title,
                    R.id.showdate, R.id.showstart, R.id.showvenue });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = myList.get(position);
            // hashMap.put("map", hashMap);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ArtistDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}

public void featured(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Featured.class));
}

public void schedule(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Schedule.class));
}

public void venue(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Venues.class));
}

public void share(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Friends.class));
}

public void myravinia(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Account.class));
}
```

Hopefully my question was clear, let me know if you need me to display any other details.

Comment: Even if you weren't looking to implement a progress dialog, you should still set up an Async task. Fetching and processing the JSONP from your UI thread will lock up the UI - not only making for a bad user experience, but also risking your app being force closed by Android.

Comment: Thats good to know.  After I get the progress icon working as the ListView load, I will need to include images into each of the line items from a url string.  You know any good tuts explaining AsyncTask with a json feed?

Comment: Android has some solid documentation regarding async tasks: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what your trying to accomplish is to make sure that the task is an asynchronous task. So when you are getting the JSON feed, it needs to be an asynchronous task because you want another task to simultaneously run which would be your progress dialog. If you didn't make it asynchronous then the progress dialog would appear to be frozen and could possibly crash the synchronous task that was running, which was your JSON feed. I would look into making your JSON feed task asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Would the asynchronous task be in the same java file, or would it be its own java file and get referenced by what I have above?  Do you know of a good tutorial?

Comment: Yes, what @PKeidel suggested. You should use a handler which there is documentation on how to use it on thE android developer site. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Events.this, "Wait", "Please wait...", false);

new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        // Do a lot of funny things with json here in background
        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                if(dialog != null)
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for the Handler, did you use java.util.loggin, or android.os?

Comment: android.os.Handler

=> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this method using asyntask

```
protected class ParsingTask extends AsyncTask<Context, String, ArrayList<Items>>   {

     private ProgressDialog loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(JsonParserActivity.this);



     protected void onPreExecute() {
         loadingDialog.setMessage("loading app store..");
         loadingDialog.show();
     }
        //items is a list of model class item 
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Items> doInBackground( Context... params )  {

        String source = getJsonString(url);


        try {
            // do ur parsing here with the above source.
           }

         catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
     }      
 catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        if (source != null) {
      }
        if (!this.isCancelled()) {
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... s)   {
        super.onProgressUpdate(s);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<Items> response )  {
            // st ur list view here
                mListView.setAdapter(new JsonListAdapter(JsonParserActivity.this));
            loadingDialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The operation was cancelled", 1).show();
    }


private String getJsonString(String url) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpGet getRequest;
        try {
            getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            return EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.  From it I was able to put together a solution.  There is a lot more code in here than before, but here is what worked.

```
public class Schedule extends ListActivity {

protected EditText searchText;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected TextView textView;
protected ImageView imageView;
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
protected ImageLoader imageLoader;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule);

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.gradiant);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {
                    0xFF95B9C7, 0xFF06357A });
    gd.setCornerRadius(2f);

    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

    new GetEventsTask().execute("blah");

}

public void featured(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Featured.class));
}

public void schedule(View view) {

}

public void venue(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Venues.class));
}

public void share(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Friends.class));
}

public void myravinia(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Account.class));
}

protected class GetEventsTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> threadList;

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Schedule.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... params) {

        Log.v("Yup", "The thread is running");
        threadList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("my.json.feed.url");

        try {


            JSONArray current = json.getJSONArray("d");

            for (int i = 0; i < current.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject e = current.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("showid", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("ShowID")));
                map.put("name", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Title")));
                map.put("showvenue", "" + e.getString("ShowVenue"));
                map.put("subtitle",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("SubTitle")));
                map.put("venueid", "" + e.getString("VenueID"));

                String showDate = e.getString("ShowDate");
                long epoch = Long.parseLong(showDate);
                Date showDatePresent = new Date(epoch * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMMM d");
                String dateOfShow = sdf.format(showDatePresent);
                map.put("showdate", "" + dateOfShow);

                String showStart = e.getString("ShowStart");
                long epoch2 = Long.parseLong(showStart);
                Date showTimePresent = new Date(epoch2 * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                String timeOfShow = sdf2.format(showTimePresent);
                map.put("showstart", "" + timeOfShow);

                String showEnd = e.getString("ShowEnd");
                long epoch3 = Long.parseLong(showEnd);
                Date showEndPresent = new Date(epoch3 * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                String endOfShow = sdf3.format(showEndPresent);
                map.put("showend", "" + endOfShow);

                String gatesOpen = e.getString("GatesOpen");
                long epoch4 = Long.parseLong(gatesOpen);
                Date gatesOpenPresent = new Date(epoch4 * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "'Gates open: 'h:mm a");
                String gatesAreOpen = sdf4.format(gatesOpenPresent);
                map.put("gatesopen", "" + gatesAreOpen);

                map.put("aboutartist", "" + e.getString("AboutArtist"));
                map.put("program",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Program")));
                map.put("programnotes",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("ProgramNotes")));
                map.put("pricing",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Pricing")));
                map.put("featuring", "" + e.getString("Featuring"));
                map.put("parkdetails", "" + e.getString("ParkDetails"));
                map.put("starred", "" + e.getString("Starred"));

                map.put("image500", "" + e.getString("Image500"));

                map.put("image250", "" + e.getString("Image250"));

                map.put("aboutartist",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("AboutArtist")));
                threadList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }

        return threadList;


    }


    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        myList = result;

        LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(Schedule.this, myList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = myList.get(position);
                // hashMap.put("map", hashMap);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ArtistDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
 }
```